# Many to many not working with select (id is ambiguous)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have problem wtih relations. I want to retrive relation of relation this model:

`Rig::with(['GPU', 'GPU.part.breakdowns'])`. But I retrive GPU.part all fields of model, I don't need it all (by the way there's select for field in Rig model).

So i write like this:

`Rig::with(['GPU', 'GPU.part:part_id,field_1,...,field_n', 'GPU.part.breakdown'])`

And now I cannot retrive breakdown relation. It's just empty array. Buy if I dont' write fields that i want to retrive, I can get several breakdowns.

Also, here is my relations

```
    // Rig.php
   // ...
   public function GPU()
   {
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany(
            Having::class,
            'rig_gpu',
            'rig_id',
            'GPU_id'
        )
        ->with([
            'part' => function ($q) {
                return $q->select([
                    'name',
                    'vendor',
                    'slug',
                    'image',
                    'field_1',
                    'field_2'
                ])->withTrashed();
            },
            'breakdown',
            'shop:shop_id,slug'
        ]);
    }
    // ...

    // Having.php
    // ...

    use \Znck\Eloquent\Traits\BelongsToThrough;
    use \Awobaz\Compoships\Compoships;

    public function part()
    {
        return $this->belongsToThrough(
            Part::class,
            PartShopPivot::class,
            'part_shop_id'
        )
            ->withTrashed('part_shop.deleted_at')
            ->withTrashed();
    }
    // ...

    // Part.php
    // ...
 
    public function breakdowns()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Breakdown::class);
    }

    // ...
```

I have select fields in Rig model

I have tried to change order of with array (`wtih(['GPU', 'GPU.part.breakdown', 'GPU.part:....'])`)

I used `'GPU.part:id'` instead of `'GPU.part:part_id`

Comment: you probably don't want to be adding a `with` to your relationship definition ... also you must select any keys needed for the relationships when defining the fields you want to load, if you leave out a foreign key it won't load the parent relationship

Comment: This also can happen when the relating columns are not of the exact same type, ie. UNSIGNED BIGINT.

Comment: @lagbox i've select `part_id`. There is no more ids for `part`

Comment: @MarkusZeller, every id field is bigint unsigned